# Create pcolor with square cells in matplotlob

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to create a pcolor mesh and i got this.

[image]

Here is the code I wrote.

```
fig=plt.figure()

X,Y=sc.meshgrid(x,y)

plt.pcolor(X,Y,z,edgecolors='k',linewidths=1,snap=True)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Is it possible to plot the pcolor graph in a way so that I have squares instead of rectangles in it?

Comment: what are x,y and z? Where should the squares be located (e.g. where should the orange pixel be located in terms of coordinates)?

Comment: x=sc.zeros((5))

    y=sc.zeros((5))

    x[0]=1

    x[1]=2

    x[2]=4

    x[3]=5

    x[4]=10

    y[0]=0.1

    y[1]=0.15

    y[2]=0.2

    y[3]=0.25

    y[4]=0.3



    z=sc.zeros((len(x),len(y)))


    for i in range(5):

        for j in range(5):

            z[i,j]=res[i*5+j,2]

Comment: I guess you did not get my point? two pixels, where one is twice as large as the other cannot both be squared on a grid, right? So you need to tell at which coordinates those pixels should then sit.

Answer (score 0):

I changed parts of the code in order to create squares. You need to have values of x,y in regularly spaces in order to create squares. (e.g. dif between x's--> 1 and  dif between y's--> 0.5.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3]

X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)

z=np.zeros((len(x),len(y)))
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        z[i,j]=i*5+j


plt.figure()
plt.pcolor(X,Y,z,edgecolors='k',linewidths=1,snap=True)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```